# Forward a request header or the security context with a Feign client RequestInterceptor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-feign

I would like to forward a request header with a feign client RequestInterceptor but, within `RequestInterceptor.apply`,  `RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()` is `null`, so is `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` (where I could also eventually get the value of my header).

This used to work before upgrading to Spring-Cloud Brixton, where the hystrix commands must now probably be run in a separate thread, because changing to the following parameter solves the problem :

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy: SEMAPHORE
```

Now, I'm not too keen on changing this kind of default values if not necessary, is there another, recommended, way of forwarding headers now ?

Thanks

Comment: You can pass `@RequestHeader` to a feign method. You could also individually set each feign call to SEMAPHORE with `hystrix.command.<methodname>.execution.isolation.strategy: SEMAPHORE`.

Comment: @spencergibb : Thanks, that's what I thought. I'll annotate the doc of my project.

Comment: I think we want to make thread vs semaphore isolation configurable in an easy manner.

Comment: @spencergibb : this could help ... but as per the netflix doc it is recommended to with the `THREAD` isolation strategy (https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#execution.isolation.strategy). In my case I think changing the isolation level to make the developement experience easier is not a good idea ... we will go with the `@RequestHeader` solution. Thanks a bunch anyways for the great work with spring cloud :-)

Comment: @SébastienNussbaumer  do you have an example. I don't quite understand how you'd get access to the RequestHeader in the Interceptor, i.e. the apply method. I'm facing a similar problem where a thread local var is returning null due to the second thread.

Comment: @imamc : The only way to get access to the RequestHeader is to change the isolation strategy with the configuration change `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.strategy: SEMAPHORE`. If you want to change this setting only for one command in particular you can also do it, as explained by spencergibb in his first comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Spring Boot 2+ / Spring Cloud Finchley +, if you just need the security context you can set the following property :

```
hystrix.shareSecurityContext=true
```

And the request interceptor should work.

---

For other uses cases or earlier versions (many thanks to [Spring Cloud Sleuth](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth) for the inspiration) :

"All" you have to do is implement an `HystrixConcurrencyStrategy` that passes the information along each time there is a thread change. The class that does something very similar in Sleuth is [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/hystrix/SleuthHystrixConcurrencyStrategy.java).

For my specific case I would :

1. Wrap the `Callable` in `wrapCallable` with, for example, an `CallableWithAuthentication` class that would hold the current authentication when constructed
2. The `CallableWithAuthentication` `call` method would first restore the previously saved `Authentication`, then call the original action, then clean up the current `Authentication`, et voilà.

Once your `HystrixConcurrencyStrategy` is up your request interceptor will work again, even with Thread isolation.

Note check the rest of the project there are lots of other interesting instrumenting stuff (for RxJava for example).

Comment: Glad that you like! Maybe you'll contribute some stuff to us then :D

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak: Time is the issue here, but hey, why not :)

Comment: This only works if you are calling feignclient from current thread. Or do you have configuration where you are calling feign client from another thread? I'm using custom threadpoolexecutor which is doing some validations and calling external services. But in this case request attributes are not propagated :(

Comment: Sure @bilak, you have to do something similar with your ThreadPoolExecutor ... Check out spring cloud sleuth, there might be code to help you do that ...

Comment: Thank you very much! Saved much time) Works on version cloud - Greenwich.RELEASE and boot -  2.1.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on @sebastian 's answer

```
public class RequestContextHystrixConcurrencyStrategy extends HystrixConcurrencyStrategy {
@Override
public <T> Callable<T> wrapCallable(Callable<T> callable) {
    return new RequestAttributeAwareCallable<>(callable, RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes());
}

static class RequestAttributeAwareCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {

    private final Callable<T> delegate;
    private final RequestAttributes requestAttributes;

    public RequestAttributeAwareCallable(Callable<T> callable, RequestAttributes requestAttributes) {
        this.delegate = callable;
        this.requestAttributes = requestAttributes;
    }

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        try {
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes);
            return delegate.call();
        } finally {
            RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
        }
    }
}
```

}

then somewhere in configuration

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerConcurrencyStrategy(new RequestContextHystrixConcurrencyStrategy());
}
```

Refer
[following post](https://www.programmersought.com/article/85724038685/)